# Domain Controller Safe Mode user account?

Tags: active-directory, windows

What account can I use to log onto a domain controller when booting into safe mode (without networking) there are no local users accounts on domain controllers and it doesn't see the domain.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the recovery password that you did set when installing the domain controller? ;) Most people overlook that - but yes, tehre is ONE emergency account and you have set the password.

Comment: I did try the active directory restore mode password.

Comment: @Jake: Then you've got the wrong password. TomTom is right re: what password is used.